# Creating ftpserver with anonymous and login both option

Tags: ftp, file-permissions, anonymous

Newbie for server.
Windows server 2012. Need to create ftp server.
The file structure will be as:
root file: read permission to all including anonymous
root\folder1: read, write permission for all including anonymous
root\folder2: read permission for all including anonymous
root\folder3: only visible to the authenticated users with read write permission.

I am expecting, when client browse, he/she will be asked with whether login with credentials or anonymous login. If anonymous, only folder 1 and folder2 will be visible. If logged in with credential, all three folders will be visible.
I have tried by setting the file permission, but I could not get the option wizard like anonymous or user login. Any suggestions please.

Comment: WHat do you mean root file?

Comment: @konard Simply the main directory of the ftp server.